# Suggested Git workflow for a WordPress Live / Dev website

Tags: git, workflow

I just wanted to here some examples about how you guys go about VC'ing WordPress websites, or any website for that matter.

Currently my workflow is:

**example.com**     - **html/live** - branch/master

**dev.example.com** - **html/dev**  - branch/dev

Make changes / editions to branch/dev and, merge them with branch/master once complete and ready to go. Then pull them on the server side via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this isn't a question... more like a suggestion.

This is also quite a common workflow, making changes to a dev branch then merging them with master to push to a live server.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this suggestion

[image]

(Source: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ )